# On the Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Assume that $d\mu=f\,dx$ for a nonnegative increasing $f$ such that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$, does it follows that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}F'\,d\mu\leq F(1)-F(0)
\end{align*}
for $F\in C^{1}[0,1]$ with $F'\geq 0$?

There is a theorem by Lebesgue saying that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}F'\,d\mu_{L}\leq F(1)-F(0),
\end{align*}
where $\mu_{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure and $F\in C^{1}[0,1]$ with $F'\geq 0$. I tried to mimic the lengthy proof, it seems that my guess is correct. But is there any reference to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $d\mu = f\,dx$ and $f$ is a smoothed version of the function
$$ \hat{f} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x\leq 1/2 \\ 2 &\text{ if } x\geq 1/2 \end{cases} $$
Then
$$ \int_{[0,1]} F' d\mu \sim 2\int_{[1/2,1]} F' \,dx = 2\left(F(1)-F(1/2)\right)$$